# Animate GPS point feature between position updates

Tags: openlayers

I want to smoothly depict the transition of my GPS marker point feature between position updates. I oriented on the "Custom Animation" example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-animation.html and animated the geometry instead of the style.

That works perfectly well. The only issue: the "original" GPS marker position feature is still visible during the animation. So while the animation is running, I have two markers: one at the old location, one being animated to the new position...
I tried setting the opacity of the original GPS marker to 0 before the animation, but I suspect, the image is already "composed" at postcompose...

Here is what I have done:

```
        function flash(feature) {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            if ((oldGPSGeometry === undefined) || (feature.getGeometry() === undefined))
                return;
            var oldCoordinates = oldGPSGeometry.getFirstCoordinate();
            var newCoordinates = feature.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate();
            if ((oldCoordinates[0] == newCoordinates[0]) && (oldCoordinates[1] == newCoordinates[1]))
                return;
            var featureStyle = feature.getStyle().clone();
            var listenerKey = map.on('postcompose', animate);

            function animate(event) {
                var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
                var frameState = event.frameState;
                var elapsed = frameState.time - start;
                var elapsedRatio = elapsed / animationDuration;
                var curCoor = [elapsedRatio * (newCoordinates[0] - oldCoordinates[0]) + oldCoordinates[0], elapsedRatio * (newCoordinates[1] - oldCoordinates[1]) + oldCoordinates[1]];
                var flashGeom = new ol.geom.Point(curCoor);
                vectorContext.setStyle(featureStyle);
                vectorContext.drawGeometry(flashGeom);
                if (elapsed > animationDuration) {
                    ol.Observable.unByKey(listenerKey);
                    return;
                }
                map.render();
            }
        }
```

I would like to "hide" the original GPS point feature during the animation. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Setting an empty style at start and resetting the original on completion works with the OpenLayers example

```
    function flash(feature) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        if ((oldGPSGeometry === undefined) || (feature.getGeometry() === undefined))
            return;
        var oldCoordinates = oldGPSGeometry.getFirstCoordinate();
        var newCoordinates = feature.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate();
        if ((oldCoordinates[0] == newCoordinates[0]) && (oldCoordinates[1] == newCoordinates[1]))
            return;
        var featureStyle = feature.getStyle();
        feature.setStyle([]);
        var listenerKey = map.on('postcompose', animate);

        function animate(event) {
            var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
            var frameState = event.frameState;
            var elapsed = frameState.time - start;
            var elapsedRatio = elapsed / animationDuration;
            var curCoor = [elapsedRatio * (newCoordinates[0] - oldCoordinates[0]) + oldCoordinates[0], elapsedRatio * (newCoordinates[1] - oldCoordinates[1]) + oldCoordinates[1]];
            var flashGeom = new ol.geom.Point(curCoor);
            vectorContext.setStyle(featureStyle);
            vectorContext.drawGeometry(flashGeom);
            if (elapsed > animationDuration) {
                ol.Observable.unByKey(listenerKey);
                feature.setStyle(featureStyle);
                return;
            }
            map.render();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. What I did instead is switching the corresponding layer on and off on exactly the lines you suggested the style setting above.
`positionLayer.setVisible(true);`
Works really well!